# как загрузить файлы из папки drawable?

Tags: android, массивы, arraylist, resources, drawable

Есть набор `.gif` с неизвестным количеством, задача - загрузить их на `layout` при нажатии на которые будет происходить действие.
Плануирую, скопировать этот набор gif с именами `0.gif`...`n.gif` в папку внутри `drawable` но как получить массив элементов? Ведь количество файлов будет меняться, и описывать `R.drawable.effect.0...` будет сложно
Нужно получить вот такой массив ссылок и применить его как `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.effect.0);`

Comment: вы не можете создавать в drawable подпапки и вы не можете изменять количество файлов в этой папке после сборки приложения(добавлять или удалять). вы вообще не можете изменять никакие файлы в любых ресурсах приложения после сборки.

Comment: Я хочу, дабы добавляя новые .gif в проект до сборки, оно автоматом вырисовывало их так как надо просто получив количество и список ссылок на элементы, поэтому я хочу узнать, как получить массив объектов, их надо ручками в лист загонять или можно как-то до создать папку, где получить ссылки на все элементы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Папки ресурсов нельзя менять в принципе.
2. Подпапки не поддерживаются. Вы можете сделать виртуальные папки. В редакторе можно будет создавать подпапки, но в итоге оно всё равно плоским будет. Разве что, работать будет удобнее. Типо [такого](https://github.com/kirill578/Android-Sorted-Res-Folder).
3. Используйте папку assets. Там можно поддиректории создавать и читать потом:

   ```
   InputStream is = null;
   try {
       is = this.getResources().getAssets().open("imgs/imgs1/0.gif");
   } catch (IOException e) {
   }
   ```
4. Называйте файлы по какому-то шаблону. К примеру, отделяйте с помощью `_` подпапки. К примеру, `imgs1_0.gif` - значит, что файл `0.gif` лежит в подпапке `imgs1`. При чтении смотрите на это.

   ```
   imgs1_0.gif
   imgs1_1.gif
   imgs2_0.gif
   imgs2_1.gif
   ```